# Why two records are inserted when i try to insert Employee object which has Manager of type Employee?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I have a classes as:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Employee Manager { get; set; }

    public virtual Department Deptartment { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

Code to create new employee in controller: This code inserts two records in DB.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Employee employee)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Employees.Add(employee);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(employee);
        }
```

I am providing MVC4 view for creating a new employee where user enter Name of employee and ManagerId. When I get the posted Employee object, it has Manager object with Id entered by user. However other details like Name is null for that object where as Employee with that userId exist in database. While inserting the Employee record in db, application is inserting two records (one for employee name entered by user and other for manager Id provided by user for that employee. For send, name is saved as null). Why two records are inserted?

Comment: what are your primary keys for table Employee? Is it only Id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a new Employee with an Subobject `Employee Manager`, you have to reload that object `Employee` because otherwise you won't get the properties for your Manager in your database. It's not enough to add just the ID.

For Example you can execute

```
public ActionResult Create(Employee employee)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        employee.Manager = db.Employees.Find(employee.Manager.Id) // load Manager properties
        db.Employees.Add(employee);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(employee);
}
```

So what happens here is the following: you reload the `Manager` object with the right properties before you post your new `Employee` object. So Entity Framework knows that the entity is already there and don't create a new object for it (if the `Id` already exists).

Comment: Isn't it kind of redundant. Because if I am assigning ManagerId means that it would be already present in table. Can I instruct EF not to create another record for MangerId?

Comment: no it's not redundant if the object isn't already loaded. BUT it depends on your primary keys. If Id is your only primary key in table Employee, you even shouldn't be a able to insert a second entry with the same Id. So maybe it depends on your table structure.